# dependancy injection in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I need to pass a model object instance to the laravel 4 controller using the following code but it gives me an error.

```
<?php

class MyController extends \BaseController {

public function index(User $user)
    {
    }
}
```

The error shown is:-

**Argument 1 passed to MyController::index() must be an instance of User, none given.**

Answer (score 1):

In this case the index method is expecting a User object to be passed to it. Instead try injecting the object into your constructor and assigning it to a class variable - hope this helps

```
<?php

class MyController extends \BaseController {

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // use $this->user to access the User object.
    }
}
```